# how to assign public IP while run the docker container in linux

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I'm new to the docker concept, i have just installed docker in my Ubuntu OS and created a container by pull from repository.

i have run the container by using the command

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 danriti/nginx-gunicorn-flask
```

i have checked with server parent IP XX.XX.98.32 (public ip) its working fine, but i have a additional public IP and i want to use that ip to host the container, so i run container as

```
docker run -d -p XX.XX.53.31:80:80 hello_world
```

its not working with my new IP XX.XX.53.31.

Can any one help me in assign public ip to docker container.

Comment: What do you mean you have "an additional public IP"? Which interface is it assigned to?

Comment: @gopinath, the second `docker run` command specifies a different image. Are you sure you're running the correct thing? Otherwise, the mapping seems fine.